# How to correctly label xticks as day names?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

the x ticks are not labeled correctly. 
1 is labeled as Tuesday
...
6 is labeled as Sunday
I would have expected 7 to be Monday, but it is not labeled

I would just like the 1 tick to be labeled Monday, ..., 7 as Sunday.
Thanks

```
import calendar

day_names = [calendar.day_name[i] for i in range(0,7)]
print(day_names)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.plot(births_per_day)
ax.set_xticklabels(day_names)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried giving a dummy name to the index 0, i.e. day_names = ['test']+day_names?

Comment: You need to set the ticks and the labels. So, use `ax.set_xticks(...)` as well

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
import calendar

day_names = [calendar.day_name[i] for i in range(0,7)]
day_names = day_names
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
ax.plot(range(7))
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(7))
ax.set_xticklabels(day_names)
plt.show()
```

Using [`ax.xaxis.set_ticks()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtnqm.png) allows you to specifically dictate the spacing of the ticks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've finally figured it out
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLlZT.png)
The code is:

```
day_names = [calendar.day_name[i] for i in range(0,7)]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(births_per_day)
ax.xaxis.set(ticks=range(1,8) ,ticklabels=day_names)
plt.show()
```